# Cross-class parameters

Tags: php, variables, object

I have these 2 classes in 2 different files

```
class Foo {      
  public $type = int;    
  function __construct($out = 1) {        
    $this->type=$out;    
  }

  public function get() {    
    return $this->type;    
  }    
}
```

AND

```
class bar {    
  function __construct {    
    echo $foo->get();    
  }    
}
```

maybe a dumb question but how come this is not working? In the above index.php file I have

```
 $vFoo = new Foo(15);
 $vBar = new Bar();
```

I though that Bar will echo Foo's type..

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Because there's no variable `$foo` created anywhere, least of all inside `bar`.

Comment: What is the `$foo` in `bar`'s `__construct`? How and where do you generate it, and how do you pass it to the `__construct`? What output do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `$foo` variable anywhere in your code and if it was, it would be out of scope. A class is not an object, [learn the basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: ok so I need to add $foo = new Foo(); inside Bar is that correct?

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve. If you just need it right there, add `$foo = new Foo();` to the constructor of Bar, yes. But note that it will be a local variable, not a property of Bar.

Comment: I want to read the foo's type (value 10) from the another class without having to creat new instance.. (How) Can this be achieved?

Comment: Well, there can be many foos, you'll have to tell your bar, which foo it should get the type of. Have you thought of `new Bar($foo);` ?

Comment: @JozkoGolonka PLEASE, do yourself a favor and read the link that was provided to you (learn the basics). What you ask for is not "impossible" - it is "absurd" (as in "I want to smell music or find out what color the number 65 is"). VALUES are stored in INSTANCES. You NEED the INSTANCE to take the value out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is:

```
class bar {

  function __construct($foo) {

    echo $foo->get();

  }

}
```

and then in the index.php:

```
$vFoo = new Foo(15); $vBar = new Bar($vFoo);
```

But what you really need is not the solution - it's [learning the basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). You don't seem to grasp what an object is and how it relates to a class (this is what your question implies; I am sure you believe otherwise).